# Determining what process has a lock on a file

Tags: vb.net, file-io, teamcity

I have a unit test that works fine locally but when uploaded to TeamCity build server fails with "The process cannot access the file  because it is being used by another process."

1. Before I do anything in the Test
   I check in the setup if the file
   exists and if so try to delete it.
   This fails with the same error
   message as above
2. When wriitng the
   file, I close the writer then
   dispose of it which I believe should
   get rid of any resources.

So I have a couple queries

1. Has anyone had similar issues and manage to get around them
2. How can find out programticall what
   process has selfishly locked the
   file!!!

Cheers

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to determine which process is holding a file in Windows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/225802/how-to-determine-which-process-is-holding-a-file-in-windows)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sysinternals [FileMon](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896642.aspx) has some information (scroll down) on how they accomplished this in older windows versions.

[Process monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx) is their latest version, but it doesn't give many clues as to how they do it.  There are some knowledge base articles linked there, though, that should lead you to this information.

-Adam

Answer (score 4):

Sysinternals [handle.exe](http://live.sysinternals.com/handle.exe) is the first step.  Or use [Process Explorer](http://live.sysinternals.com/procexp.exe)'s `Find Handle or DLL`.  It's always safer to **kill the process** than close the handle, though.

Programmatically, it's a matter of writing a kernel driver that reads the Windows handle table.

Answer (score 2):

[ProcessMon](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx) (for finding) and [Unlocker](http://www.emptyloop.com/unlocker/) (at least for unlocking) are useful too.