# Process that access a file in C#

Tags: c#, file

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I find out which process is locking a file using .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/317071/how-do-i-find-out-which-process-is-locking-a-file-using-net)

I wanna to know which process access to specific file that i chosen. Can any one introduce me a way of programmatically ( in C# ) or not to achieve this ?

NOTE: I wanna know which process lock a file that other proccess couldnt access to it !

Thanks for your attention :)

Comment: Your question is not very clear. Can you make it clearer so we can help. I am not sure whether you are looking to open a file or whatever else?

Comment: Does this help?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/860656/how-does-one-figure-out-what-process-locked-a-file-using-c