# In .NET how do you tell the name of the user who is currently locking a file on a network share?

Tags: .net, file, networking

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does one figure out what process locked a file using c#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/860656/how-does-one-figure-out-what-process-locked-a-file-using-c)

When you try to open a locked excel file, for example, you see a message displaying the name of the user currently using the file. How do I get the same info using .NET?

Comment: If I remember correctly, this information is stored specifically by Excel (and other Office products) in the little temp files it creates alongside a file when you open it. They're not using a filesystem feature. On the other hand, there is a facility for Administrators to view open remote file handles, but that wouldn't help if you're dealing with a user who has the file open locally on the machine with the share.

Answer (score 0):

Look at [WhoSLocking](http://www.kartmann.org/freeware/WhoSLocking/ReadMe.htm). It is a C++ app that comes with source code and shows you which users are locking a file.

Also look at [Using C#, how does one figure out what process locked a file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/860656) for a code sample of getting the process that locked the file. It may help you converting the C++ code in the first link.