# How to handle file creation process?

Tags: c#, winapi, event-handling, filesystems, kernel

I know how works FileSystemWatcher in C#.

It allows us to give a message when file is already created.
no matter which program/process has created this file!
Or it allows us to give information about what is a name of created file, or when it was created "few second ago"...
Also it allows us to give a message about file which was deleted or changed.

But it does not allows us to create that kind of event:
when file is being creating, but it is not yet/still created!
what if I want to terminate or pause the file creation process programmatically?

For example I want to handle or terminate file creation process programmatically according it's information which tells us that size of this file is 4GB?
no matter which program/process is trying to create this file!

Or there is another question:
What if I want to calculate when was file creation started and when was it created? as well distance between this two dates!?
I think you understood that we need more info about file before process will start to create it!

I think you might know that in windows 10 the explorer.exe allows us to do it anytime!

[image]

It even allows us to resume a copy process any time!
So if it is possible to do it in explorer.exe then it also might be possible to do it using .NET
But forget this resume capability of explorer.exe

I just need to cancel any file creation process for example if the size of this file is 4GB!
no matter which program is trying to create file!

So please help me to find out How to pop up a messageBox during file creation process?

---

Thank you!
Sorry my bad English!

Comment: then search through the processes and find which process is making the file and terminated it - there's no guarantees - didn't you ask this almost identical question a moment ago?

Comment: yes! I have asked and now I improved! Also remember that we are talking about a lot of file creations. All this means that my .net application itself must search through the processes and find which process is making the file and terminated it!

Comment: but you cant always terminate a process.. you may not have permission.. plus, you're terminating the process, not the filewrite.. it could make a hell of a mess

Comment: If you will help me I will be happy! Thank you anyway!

Comment: I will use try catch block!

Comment: [How to find out which process](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/860656/using-c-how-does-one-figure-out-what-process-locked-a-file) it doesnt take much, open google, type stuff in

Comment: thank you! This might be useful! But How much I dont know!

Comment: that covers the complete how to find out which process... thats like 99% of it

Answer (score 1):

The only way to be notified about the file operation before it is actually performed is to utilize a filesystem filter driver. This is a kernel-mode driver which you need to write in C. There exist samples of such drivers in the internet. An alternative to writing such driver yourself is to use one of the libraries that include pre-created filter drivers and let you handle all or chosen filesystem requests in user-mode (including .NET). Our company offers CallbackFilter product for this purpose.

Comment: But can you tell me the name of one of those libraries! Please!

Comment: @IremadzeArchil19910311 Our CallbackFilter is the one, and there was EaseFilter there as well.

Comment: @IremadzeArchil19910311 There is also the library Dokan. It is totally Free and opensource (https://github.com/dokan-dev/dokany). It has a C# wrapper (https://github.com/dokan-dev/dokan-dotnet) that answer your need (I am one of the main maintainers).

Comment: @Liryna and has nothing to do with the question asked by the OP.

Comment: Please look at the OP question in his comment of your answer.

Comment: @Liryna your comments are not applicable because dokan doesn't do what the OP needs, not because the OP asked for the names of the libraries. Dokan can't intercept the operation performed in C:\Windows, for example.

Comment: With quick changes of the Dokan Mirror, this is absolutly possible. Also OP is not talking about C:\Windows.

Comment: @Liryna "I just need to cancel any file creation process" which includes c:\windows . And of course the mirror won't help as one needs a filter driver rather than a filesystem driver.