# Get process name when catching UnauthorizedAccessException

Tags: c#, process, exception, kill

I'm making an update software who could raise exceptions if unknown process are running.

There is a way during catching an UnauthorizedAccessException to get the process name who cause problems, kill this process and continue my update?

Thanks

Comment: Are you asking how to determine the process locking an executable file? - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/860656/using-c-how-does-one-figure-out-what-process-locked-a-file

Comment: Yeah, like when I try to replace an executable file but it runs in background, I want to kill it and replace it.