# file renaming problem?

Tags: c#, file, file-rename

Renaming a file in c#:

```
File.Move(source,Destination);
            File.Delete(source);
```

It execute successfully, how ever when i try to rename the file again, the system gives this exception: 
**The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.**
i cant find that where is this in use? when i further debug the error it shows me the class name is in the process of w3wp.exe which is IIS. What should i do next?
getting

```
foreach (string folder in folder)
{ 
 FileSystemItem item = new FileSystemItem(); 
 DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(folder); 
 item.Name = di.Name;
 item.FullName = di.FullName; 
 item.Path = path + "\\" + item.Name;
 item.CreatedDate = di.CreationTime; 
 item.IsFolder = true; 
 item.Extension = "folder";
 listFolder.Add(item);
}
docList = CreatXmllist(listFolder); 
return docList
```

this is how i am getting folder list and it is then returned to xml. then in folder i get the files when i click it

now to get the images: this is the code

```
public xml (string path, List<l> one)
    {

        List<T> tt = new List<T>();
        List<T> SessionList = new List<T>();
        string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(HttpContext.Current.Request.PhysicalApplicationPath + path);

        foreach (string file in files)
        {
            FileSystemItem item = new FileSystemItem();
            FileInfo i = new FileInfo(file);
            string  a = i.LastWriteTime.ToString();
            var thumbnails = from a in b where a.Name == fi.Name select t;

            if (fi.Name != "a")
                if (t.Count() == 0)
                {
                    r session r = new r();
                    r.aName = fi.aName;
                    SessionList.Add(r);
                    fi.Exists;
                }
                else
                    t.Add((T)t.First());

        }
```

Comment: Why are you deleting the source after you renamed it?

Comment: @ Golez Trol:because i moved the file(just like copying) and rename it to the new name.

Comment: I think no need for the second line

Comment: @Hallie: i removed the file.delete(source) and still it giving me the error :(

Comment: Have you tried renaming the file manually? to see if no other processes is using the file.

Comment: @Hallie: sorry i was wrong, no in the system it also cant be rename

Comment: Have you got another programm whitch may use file? antivirus etc. Try to swith them all off. Or may be your programm use that file in some way

Comment: @anton Semenov: When i use it in debugger, so its says, file is used by W3WP process, Which is windows process.Now i do not how to solve this :(

Comment: w3wp process is the IIS process...

Comment: @Peter Van Kekem:yes and my class i.e Rename is in this process, so what should i do now, to get out of this?

Comment: @safi Have you opened that file anywhere else in the app?  I expect it's your own app that hase a handle open.  Try using [try-finally](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zwc8s4fz(v=vs.71).aspx) wherever you are reading or writing to that file.

Comment: @C. Ross I have not opened the file any where.when i log-off from the application and log-in again then some time it dont give this error, i am using try and catch where it give me this error.

Comment: @safi Can you provide more details about the file and how it's being used in your application, or other applications in IIS?

Comment: geting folder  `foreach (string folder in folder)
 { FileSystemItem item = new FileSystemItem();
  DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(folder);
item.Name = di.Name;
                    item.FullName = di.FullName;
                    item.Path = path + "\\" + item.Name;
                    item.CreatedDate = di.CreationTime;
 item.IsFolder = true;
item.Extension = "folder";
listFolder.Add(item); } docList = CreatXmllist(listFolder);
return docList`
this is how i am getting folder list and it is then returned to xml. then in folder i get the files when i click it.

Comment: @ C. Ross after getting the folder when i click the folder i can see the files, then when any attempt is made to rename/delete than i get that error:(

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to call the File.Delete as part of the rename, you would have needed it if you did a copy.

Comment: i removed the file.delete(source) and still it giving me the error :(

Answer (score 1):

Try using the FileShare enumerator. Then try to open a file with monesharing, close the handle and if there is no exception you can move the file.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.io.fileshare.aspx

It contains the methods Read, Write etc.

Comment: `FileStream s2 = new FileStream(name, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read);` there is a parameter fileshare.read, so then it will be possible to delete if it is already opened by another user?

Comment: ok thanks, i am trying to do it, then i have to specify the s2 in the file.move(source,dest) , so it will be like file.move(s2,destination) ?

Comment: @safi You need to close any readers or writers *before* doing a move.  Even if the file is sharing for reading and writing you can't move it while it's open.

Answer (score 1):

Create a `FileInfo` instance, in which you can rename it more than once.

```
FileInfo file = new FileInfo(source);
file.MoveTo(destination);

// execute more code

file.MoveTo(destination2)
```

Comment: Could you please post more details about the exception? (Stacktrace, inner exception, maybe something from the event viewer)

Comment: can i get some help regarding this issue?

Comment: If you debug the issue you get the exception in Visual Studio. There you can click on "View Detail", where you can find more details about your exception.