# Delete image from path

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

What do I need to do to end imagePath process?

Error:

> The process cannot access the file
>   'C:\Users\Rafal\7074edcf-8849-4ea7-a87d-e2e8b5890f3f.jpg' because it
>   is being used by another process.

[image]

```
public WrappedJsonResult2 UploadImageSmall(HttpPostedFileWrapper imageFile2)
        {

            if (imageFile2 == null || imageFile2.ContentLength == 0)
            {
                return new WrappedJsonResult2
                {
                    Data = new
                    {
                        IsValid = false,
                        Message = "Nie dodano zdjęcia",
                        ImagePath = string.Empty
                    }
                };
            }
```

here I have fileName and imagePath for first picture

```
            var fileName = String.Format("{0}.jpg", Guid.NewGuid().ToString());
            var imagePath = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath(Url.Content("~/Content/UserImages")), fileName);
```

here I have fileName and imagePath for second picture

```
            var fileNameZmniejszony = String.Format("{0}.jpg", Guid.NewGuid().ToString());
            var imagePathZmniejszony = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath(Url.Content("~/Content/UserImages")), fileNameZmniejszony);
```

I save picture from JSON

```
            imageFile2.SaveAs(imagePath);
```

I take picture from direction of imageFile2

```
            var image = Image.FromFile(imagePath);
```

I scale new picture and save as second Image

```
            var newImage = ScaleImage(image, 300, 400);
            newImage.Save(imagePathZmniejszony);
```

Here I would like to delete file with directory first image

```
            if (System.IO.File.Exists(imagePath))
            {
                System.IO.File.Delete(imagePath);
            }

            var model = new StronaGlowna();
            if (!TryUpdateModel(model))
            {
            }
            model.MaleZdjecie = String.Format("~/Content/UserImages/{0}", fileNameZmniejszony);

            return new WrappedJsonResult2
            {
                Data = new
                {
                    IsValid = true,
                    Message = string.Empty,
                    ImagePath = Url.Content(String.Format("~/Content/UserImages/{0}", fileNameZmniejszony))
                }
            };
        }
```

Why I have got problem with process because this take process (HttpPostedFileWrapper imageFile2)

and dispose() will not work for this problem.

Comment: Duplicate of [The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/877889/the-process-cannot-access-the-file-because-it-is-being-used-by-another-process)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to `Dispose()` your image before you'll be able to delete it.  Right now, you have the image file opened.

This is documented in [`Image.FromFile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/stf701f5.aspx)

> The file remains locked until the Image is disposed.

In your code, one way to handle this is to write:

```
using(var image = Image.FromFile(imagePath))
{
   using(var newImage = ScaleImage(image, 300, 400))
   {
       newImage.Save(imagePathZmniejszony);
   }
}
```

This will cause both `Image` instances to be Disposed of properly.

Comment: when I try this I get similar error ->  var image4 = Image.FromFile(imagePath);
            image4.Dispose();

Comment: @Rafael-JuniorMVCDeveloper "image" still has it locked...  Your new code needs to Dispose image AND image4

Comment: problem is bigger because my file is (HttpPostedFileWrapper imageFile2) and probably this imageFile2 have got process and .Dispose() will not work for this. I would like to know answer for that but users closed my post.

Comment: @Rafael-JuniorMVCDeveloper That actually shouldn't be an issue.  You don't need to dispose of that one, only the `Image` instances.

Comment: Can you look on my edited post? Probably before I did not make good explanation?

Comment: @Rafael-JuniorMVCDeveloper Replace the code from `image = ` to `newImage.Save` with mine above, and it should work fine.

Comment: thanks it`s working correct. Thanks one more time.

Answer (score 2):

Try using `image.Dispose()` before deleting it.

Comment: imagePath is a string.

Comment: logicaly true (for dispose), but not `imagepath.Dispose();`, `image.Dispose();`

Comment: @tijizor I get error -> Error 1 'System.Web.HttpPostedFileWrapper' does not contain a definition for 'Dispose' and no extension method 'Dispose' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Web.HttpPostedFileWrapper' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Also, using statement more elegant than dispose like @ReedCopsey suggestion...

Comment: @Rafael-JuniorMVCDeveloper I believe that is because your image is a `var` type. Is there a reason behind this ?

Answer (score 2):

You need to dispose your image variable. It is still using the file.

call `image.Dispose();` before doing the delete.

You can also wrap your image variable in an using statement when you go to copy it. This is better practice.

```
using (var image = Image.FromFile(imagePath))
{
    var newImage = ScaleImage(image, 300, 400);
    newImage.Save(imagePathZmniejszony);
}
```

The above will fix the issue. Always wrap disposable objects in an Using statement. That clears all unmanaged resources from memory.