# Java.Lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo while adding SplashActivity

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, splash-screen

I'm stuck on an issue while adding Splash screen using Xamarin Forms. I have implemented the splash screen with help of [this link](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/user_interface/splash-screen/).

After that the app crashed. and show the given error popup.

Please help me
Thank you

[image]

Comment: share your code snippet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could refer to Jon Douglas's answer : [Xamarin.Android app only finding launcher activity on clean compile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48425799/xamarin-android-app-only-finding-launcher-activity-on-clean-compile/48427487#48427487)
.

> This issue has been fixed and be included in `Visual Studio 15.5.5` or `Visual Studio 15.6 Preview 3`.
>
> The respective Xamarin.Android version this fix is included in are `Xamarin.Android 8.1.5.0 (Stable)` and `Xamarin.Android 8.2.0.6 (Preview)`

## Solution 1:

Update your Visual Studio to the latest version, Visual Studio 15.5.6 is available now.

## Solution 2:

- Delete your solution bin&obj folder
- Rebuild again

Comment: Thank you for your support.