# How do I determine which program is using a file in VB 2005?

Tags: .net, vb.net, file, process

Is there a way to get the program that is locking a file, in vb 2005?

For instance, when I try to open a file that is already opened by another program, can I get the name of the process/program that has locked this file?

Comment: I've gotta say this is not a duplicate the previously liked question is about c# this is VB.

Comment: However there is a relevant answer there, although it only works for Dlls http://stackoverflow.com/questions/317071/how-do-i-find-out-which-process-is-locking-a-file-c/317209#317209

Answer (score 3, accepted):

System Internals has a tool called [Handle](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896655.aspx) that you can use. It tells you which program has what file and/or directory open. It is a console application. You can pipe its output to a text file and then simply open that text file and search for the file you're looking for. Then you can see which process has it open.

```
c:\handle > output.txt
```

Comment: You can also install ProcessExplorer from the same SysInternals Suite ( download at http://download.sysinternals.com/Files/SysinternalsSuite.zip ) and look for handles in the search box. This way you can even kill the offending process (or thread if you like living on the edge).
But handle is a lot faster.