# Can't use bitmap.Save

Tags: c#, .net, windows, bitmap, gdi+

I want to make a screen capturer that can capture many times whenever the user clicked it (I want to create my own, so don't just tell me that there's a software for that, and for my own practice too) :)

[Bitmap.Save "Generic Error"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13576806/bitmap-save-generic-error)

I tried searching all of the possible solutions from StackOverflow (Above link is one of the many that I've found), but I can't any that can help with my problem.

**This is my Code**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Screen_Monitoring
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void btnCaptureScreen_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            String screenName = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "ScreenImages/screen.jpg";
            CaptureScreen(screenName);
            screen1.Image = Image.FromFile(screenName);
        }

        private void CaptureScreen(String screenName)
        {
            Rectangle bounds = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds;
            using (Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(bounds.Width, bounds.Height))
            {
                using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap))
                {
                    g.CopyFromScreen(new Point(bounds.Left, bounds.Top), Point.Empty, bounds.Size);
                }
                bitmap.Save(screenName, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The problem occurs when I tried to save my Picture Box twice (It always happened the second time)

Error Message: System.Runtime.InteropServices.ExternalException: 'A generic error occurred in GDI+.'

**This is my Form**

[image: Form Image]

Don't mind ScreenCapture.cs, that's just one of the other solution I tried to try Screen Capturing.

**EDIT-FOR-DUPLICATE**
I've tried [Overwrite Existing Image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8905714/overwrite-existing-image) just now, and it's still the same error as before.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Screen_Monitoring
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void btnCaptureScreen_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            String screenName = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "ScreenImages/screen.jpg";
            if (File.Exists(screenName)) File.Delete(screenName);
            CaptureScreen(screenName);
            screen1.Image = Image.FromFile(screenName);
        }

        private Image GetCopyImage(string path)
        {
            using (Image im = Image.FromFile(path))
            {
                Bitmap bm = new Bitmap(im);
                return bm;
            }
        }

        private void CaptureScreen(String screenName)
        {
            Rectangle bounds = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds;
            using (Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(bounds.Width, bounds.Height))
            {
                using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap))
                {
                    g.CopyFromScreen(new Point(bounds.Left, bounds.Top), Point.Empty, bounds.Size);
                }
                bitmap.Save(screenName, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
                bitmap.Dispose();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now this is where I got the error (Again, after the second click)

```
if (File.Exists(screenName)) File.Delete(screenName);
```

Error Message: System.IO.IOException: 'The process cannot access the file 'C:\Users\Michael HT\Documents\2. Work\Project\Screen Monitoring\Screen Monitoring\bin\Debug\ScreenImages\screen.jpg' because it is being used by another process.'

**EDIT-ADDING-NULL-BEFORE-DELETING**

```
private void btnCaptureScreen_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            String screenName = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "ScreenImages/screen.jpg";
            screen1.Image = null;
            if (File.Exists(screenName)) File.Delete(screenName);
            CaptureScreen(screenName);
            screen1.Image = Image.FromFile(screenName);
        }
```

I tried adding null before deleting, still got the same error at

```
if (File.Exists(screenName)) File.Delete(screenName);
```

Error Message: System.IO.IOException: 'The process cannot access the file 'C:\Users\Michael HT\Documents\2. Work\Project\Screen Monitoring\Screen Monitoring\bin\Debug\ScreenImages\screen.jpg' because it is being used by another process.'

**EDIT-FOR-THE-SOLUTION**

I tried this and it worked!!

```
private void btnCaptureScreen_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            String screenName = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "ScreenImages/screen.jpg";
            if(screen1.Image != null) screen1.Image.Dispose();
            screen1.Image = null;
            CaptureScreen(screenName);
            screen1.Image = Image.FromFile(screenName);
        }
```

Here's the correct code :)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Screen_Monitoring
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void btnCaptureScreen_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            String screenName = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "ScreenImages/screen.jpg";
            if(screen1.Image != null) screen1.Image.Dispose();
            screen1.Image = null;
            CaptureScreen(screenName);
            screen1.Image = Image.FromFile(screenName);
        }

        private Image GetCopyImage(string path)
        {
            using (Image im = Image.FromFile(path))
            {
                Bitmap bm = new Bitmap(im);
                return bm;
            }
        }

        private void CaptureScreen(String screenName)
        {
            Rectangle bounds = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds;
            using (Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(bounds.Width, bounds.Height))
            {
                using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap))
                {
                    g.CopyFromScreen(new Point(bounds.Left, bounds.Top), Point.Empty, bounds.Size);
                }
                bitmap.Save(screenName, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks for the help!!

Comment: You need to release all references to the file before overwriting it. Not as simple as one might think..!

Comment: Since it "always happens the second time".. are you sure it doesn't happen once it tries to overwrite the file created "the first time"?

Comment: @TaW How do I do that? Sorry I'm new in GDI :(

Comment: @MihaiOvidiuDrăgoi Yes I'm sure, I've got the folder for ScreenImages, so that's not the problem for my issue

Comment: @TaW I've updated my question, as per your Mark as Duplicate. Like I said before, how do I release all references to the file before overwritting it? I know what you mean, but I don't know how, every possible "Dispose" function that I've found, I tried it already and got the same error. I've tried that File Exist then Delete too even before I asked here.

Comment: Hm, is that actually the same error??

Comment: Is screen1 a PictureBox? Try to set its Image to null before deleting the file!

Comment: @TaW Oh yeah, I just notice it that one of the error was done and now I'm up for the next error :( I can't delete an opened file, so how do I close the file? And i tried adding `screen1.Image = null`, not working too, still the same error. "Being used for another process"

Comment: @TaW Thanks for the help, I already updated my question with an answer there :) Apparently, I need to dispose of my picturebox.Image first.

Comment: Correct. This works here: `private void btnCaptureScreen_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    String screenName =...;
    Image img = screen1.Image;
    if (img != null) img.Dispose();
    screen1.Image = null;
    if (File.Exists(screenName)) File.Delete(screenName);
    CaptureScreen(screenName);
    screen1.Image = Image.FromFile(screenName);
}`

Comment: @TaW Thanks a lot!! :)

Comment: Careful... calling `screen1.Image.Dispose()` directly can give an `ObjectDisposedException` if the UI tries to repaint it. It's much safer to put it in a new variable, then set `screen1.Image` to null, and then dispose the image from the other variable.