# Catch access to the path is denied exception

Tags: c#, winforms

This is my Class who return the newest file from each directory, the problem is that albeit i put my code in Try - Catch block i still got the error that path is denied

```
public class NewestFiles
{
    //public event EventHandler newFileEventHandler;

    // Dictionary: 
    //   Key = The directory name.
    //   Value = The most recently modified file for that directory.
    private Dictionary<string, string> GetNewestFiles(string directory, Dictionary<string, string> dictionary)
    {
        if (dictionary == null)
            dictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);

        try
        {
            var files = from file in Directory.GetFiles(directory, "*.*")
                        select new FileInfo(file);

            var latestFile = files.OrderByDescending(file => { return file.LastWriteTimeUtc; }).FirstOrDefault();

            if (latestFile != null)
                dictionary[latestFile.DirectoryName] = latestFile.FullName;
        }
        catch(Exception)
        { }

        foreach (var subDirectory in Directory.GetDirectories(directory))
        {
            try
            {
                GetNewestFiles(subDirectory, dictionary);
            }
            catch { }
        }

        return dictionary;
    }

    public Dictionary<string, string> GetNewestFiles(string directory)
    {
        return GetNewestFiles(directory, null);
    }
}
```

Comment: What does this mean? In which line does it happen?
Did you get the exception and your debugger warns you, or does the exception crash the application?

Comment: Also, I think there might be a problem with your code: you did not guard against  nfts junction folders which can cause infinite loops and additionally, if you acess a temp file, this may be gone when you use the dictionary entries...

Comment: The exception occur in var files = from file in Directory.GetFiles(directory, "*.*")
                            select new FileInfo(file);

Comment: Can i have an code example how to do it ?

Comment: Exception is not an error, but an opportunity to deal with the error. Catching an exception and doing nothing in catch clause is bad programming (with very few exceptions, no pun intended).

Answer (score 0):

> albeit i put my code in Try - Catch block i still got the error that path is denied

Try catch do not prevent errors they only catch exception for you to handle in a nice way if something bad happens

Now your error

> access to the path is denied exception

As the error itself suggest that you don't have acces to the file/directory that you are trying to read. or if you have written that file yourself (as it seems from your code) it is possible that you haven't properly closed the writer.

Answer (score 0):

usually when you get `access to the path is denied exception` it means some other program is holding the file. when you are dealing with files, streams or databases you should use the `using` statement in order to prevent from not closing streams.

however, there are ways to take the file forcibly or at least find out which process locking it. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/317071/how-do-i-find-out-which-process-is-locking-a-file-using-net) you can see how to get started with it