# How do I close another process to release file locks?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, file, io

I have created a button. In the event handler for the button I want to delete all the files in the folder (abc).

Here is the code for this:

```
    private void button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Are you sure!!!! The files in the folder will be deleted permanently");
        this.Close();
        string[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\abc\");
        foreach (string filePath in filePaths)
            File.Delete(filePath);
    }
```

For example, there is a Word file in the folder and if it is opened I get a error message:

> The process cannot access the file 'C:\abc\New Microsoft Word
>   Document.docx' because it is being used by another process.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/317071/how-do-i-find-out-which-process-is-locking-a-file-using-net there are samples to find process holding the lock.

Comment: @gp. this is the original thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/876473/is-there-a-way-to-check-if-a-file-is-in-use/11060322#11060322

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Process` class to find that process, forcibly close that program and then delete that file. Something like this...

```
Process [] proc Process.GetProcessesByName("winword");
proc[0].Kill();
```

However I wouldn't suggest this because windows also do not delete opened files.

Comment: Any more suggesstions????