# what process is locking the directory when try to change the LastWrite datetime?

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms, visual-studio-2013, file-locking

I am writing within a heavily managed async (single) thread. it is a FIFO queue in a thread and `something` is locking my attempt to do a `Directory.SetLastWriteTime`. It is almost certainly me. but I can't see it. I used [**this link**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/317071/how-do-i-find-out-which-process-is-locking-a-file-using-net): and as part of it I tried to use [`Handle`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896655.aspx) but c# wouldn't understand the reference to `handle.exe` (failed at line `tool.Start();`) despite the path to handle.exe being in the system path and it running fine in command.

The problem is I then tried to use the [`FileUtil`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/317071/how-do-i-find-out-which-process-is-locking-a-file-using-net) example code lower down the answers list but this only works on `files` I need to see what is locking a `folder`. bear in mind this folder is not really locked, I can change the `LastModifiedDate` in `Attribute Changer 7` so it is certainly my queue that is dong it wrong.

this is the code I am actually trying to run, that continually says it is locked.

```
System.DateTime newDateTime = new DateTime(2011,1,1,0,0,0,0,System.DateTimeKind.Utc);
if (Directory.Exists(parent))
{
    Unlocker.unlock(parent); //<--new line
    Directory.SetLastWriteTime(parent, newDateTime);
}
```

note that I suspect `FileUtil` works fine for files but I need to modify a `folder` and it is bombing badly. Can anyone help me get the Process locking a given directory not just a file?

**EDIT** (see also, `<<- new line` above) I have abandoned `FileUtil` but I am now using  `handle.exe` successfully (i.e. if I manually lock it by trying to to give it mouse focus in windows explorer for example it detects it) but handle returns no "locks" when the c# bombs:

```
public static class Unlocker
{
  public static void unlock(string fileName)
  {
    Process tool = new Process();
    tool.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\Handle\handle.exe";
    tool.StartInfo.Arguments = fileName + " /accepteula";
    tool.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    tool.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    tool.Start();
    tool.WaitForExit();
    string outputTool = tool.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();

    string matchPattern = @"(?<=\s+pid:\s+)\b(\d+)\b(?=\s+)";
    foreach (Match match in Regex.Matches(outputTool, matchPattern))
    {
            Debug.WriteLine("Unlocker.unlock(`" + fileName + "`) is locked by `" + Process.GetProcessById(int.Parse(match.Value)).ProcessName + "`");
    }
  }
}
```

**SECOND EDIT**
the SetWriteTime was working all along, it was a looping issue further up the code line, it didn't work when the user has mouse clicked on the folder (which I had been doing accidentally randomly) but the bad outer loop was perpetuating it - a bad finally forever causing a loop counter exception with a faulty "file is locked" message.

Comment: *heavily managed async (single) thread* - can you dissect that phrase a bit? What does "heavily managed" mean? Is your app the only app which is accessing the folder? From my experience, having the folder open in Windows Explorer, or a file from that folder, will prevent you from changing this attribute.

Comment: it's non GUI thread and it's a heavy lifting thread that does downloads / uploads in sequence.. there are over 16 such operations but they never clash.. as such it waits for items to be complete. what I suspect is that a download has only "just" finished so the lock is possibly the remains of the downloading but I am not sure. There are no other locks on the folder.

Comment: But what's the point of setting last write time? Are you using this for some kind of internal syncing, or is this really a requirement?

Comment: @Groo it's a question about what process is directory locking

Comment: That's probably better suited for [SuperUser](http://superuser.com/) then (since you're actually only using `Handle` and `FileUtil` to find what is locking the folder).

Comment: sigh.. it's actually pretty simple, but since you've decided to force me to go into unnecessary detail: I want to download a folder and make sure that the last modified date is the same as the source folder not when the download happened, it's a c# question nothing to do with file management per se - it's exactly the same as the linked (SO) question but it needs to be for folders not just file

Comment: Why do you need to call handle.exe programmatically? Can't you just call it from the command line to diagnose which process is locking the directory? You will then have a better understanding of the problem and what the permanent fix might be. What extra is calling it programmatically going to give you? I also like Process Explorer (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) for finding what is locking what (and other things--it is a Task Manager replacement).

Comment: @ShellShock because the lock isn't there when I look for it - I actually specifically say this in the OP

Comment: can we just cancel this question I am not interested in repeatedly having to justify my question to people who can't/won't give an answer! I think SO has destroyed the ability to ask sensible questions: like "hey you know that you can get a file lock information, we how about you help me get folder lock information the same way" that is a easy question (probably not an easy answer, but an easy question) and nothing has come back but me having to justify the question; it's a total waste of all our time stop doing it please

Comment: I will persevere; apologies for not realising that "It is almost certainly me. but I can't see it" means that handle.exe is not reporting any locks. What does "this is the code I am actually trying to run, that continually says it is locked." mean? Are you getting an exception. If so, please post details of the exception. Also I still think it is worth giving Process Explorer a go.

Comment: I have updated the OP to try to cover what is going on

Comment: @ShellShock it was (it seems) a wild goose hunt or  a red herring :-/ I first got a lock error, I then introduced a tonne of protective code - but the lock error was legitimate: it was me having mouse focus on the explorer window and the tonne of protection code was faulty and thereby replicated an error every time that said there was a fault but there want't - it HAD been changing the datetime