# Retrieve user with Powershell

Tags: powershell

In Powershell, I've managed to check if a file is locked for editing ("The document is locked for editing by another user").

But I cannot retrieve some information about the user.
How can I retrieve which user locked the file?

Comment: Invoke `handle.exe` or marshal the [relevant functions from the kernel api](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3504251/712649) to find the locking process, then call `GetOwner()` on that process

Comment: Sorry: the user is from another computer on the network.

Comment: Doesn't matter, should still work