# Capture File and Folder Opening events

Tags: java, c#, file, logging, filesystems

**Background *(not related though)*** : I have a friend who live in HOSTEL, his roommates aren’t very trustworthy people, he said to me, to make something for him, so that He could know which files and folders were opened in his absence by his roommates? *(They have a mutual agreement of not opening someone personal folders)* *(He is supposed to share PC and can’t hide or encrypt his personal folders)*
So I decided to go with C# because my friend is using Windows OS.

**Required Behavior :** So The task is to make a Windows Form Application that will logs name and location of every file and folder opened by user in the Windows Explorer, during the application running time.

**What I Tried :** I tried to use a class of `FileSystemWatcher` but it only has four events of Changed, Created, Deleted & Renamed which I don’t need at all, It doesn’t matter if user is changing or deleting or creating or renaming something, all it does matter is which files & folders are opened by user ...?

If it could be done in Java I am also ready to give it a shot, just point me in the right direction !!

Comment: In order to get help, please provide a [MCVE].

Comment: That is explained in the link [MCVE]

Comment: I can't give you the code since you have not provided any code that you have tried. There are some resources you may refer to get the idea. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33805734/get-username-of-user-who-has-file-open-on-network-drive-microsoft-office-style, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/317071/how-do-i-find-out-which-process-is-locking-a-file-using-net/20623311#20623311, https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/a5014c25-eaf0-41d2-9c8a-506aff38748e/how-can-i-tell-who-has-a-file-open?forum=Vsexpressvcs

Answer (score 0):

why you even need a program for that when windows captures this functionality already just press window+R and type recent and enter and it will show all opened files