# How to Copy a file which is already being used

Tags: c#, winforms, copy-paste

I have two files (`.mdf` and `.ldf`) in the `App_Data` folder. Now I want to copy these 2 files and need to paste into backup folder while running the application. But I'm getting an error:

> The process cannot access the file 'D:\App_Data\' because it is
>   being used by another process.

These is my code I've been using

```
string dir = Directory.GetDirectories(@"D:\","App_data").FirstOrDefault();
string targetPath = @"D:\Back_up_PayRoll\";

if (System.IO.Directory.Exists(dir))
{
    string[] files = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(dir);

    if (!Directory.Exists(targetPath))
        Directory.CreateDirectory(targetPath);

    foreach (string s in files)
    {
        var fileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(s);

        var destFile = System.IO.Path.Combine(targetPath, fileName);
        System.IO.File.Copy(s, destFile, true);
        MessageBox.Show("BACK-UP Done..");
    }
}
```

Comment: Use Volume Shadow Copy : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shadow_Copy

Comment: Then How to Stop  the process of file is being used by Another Application

Comment: Sounds like an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/161449). What are you *actually* trying to do? Why do you need to copy your database files while they are in use by your own application?

Comment: yes @ zespri, I need to copy those files as backup

Comment: @FernandoSucre then either stop the database (gracefully, not killing the process), or use shadow copy. Killing the database process which may be writing to it at the time is definitely **NOT** a good idea. Killing a stuck process as an emergency measure is one thing. Killing it routinely just because it's locking a file is not. Locks exist for a reason

Comment: Those are **SQL Server** data and transaction log files - **DO NOT** just simply copy those! Use the proper SQL Server `BACKUP DATABASE` command to back up a SQL Server database!

Comment: As mark_s says, copying files is NOT how you back up a database. *This* is why it's important, that you explain what you are actually trying to do, as you already have. You were trying to solve a wrong problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If available on the system, you could use a snapshot using the [Volume Shadow Copy Service](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384649(v=vs.85).aspx)

From C#, there's the handy [AlphaVSS](http://alphavss.alphaleonis.com/) library that wraps the COM interface, but you could implement it directly.

If VSS is not available, then tough luck, no way around a file lock

*PS: of course, this ain't as easy as `File.Copy`*

Comment: Then How to Stop of a file is being used by Another Process

Comment: You may check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3504251/68972)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot access an MDF file in any way without disconnecting from it first.

Best bet is backing it up using SQL, or shutting down your application and copying it by running a BAT file

Comment: I'm not using Sql Server by the way...