# How can I know which process hold the file when I fail to delete the file and get an exception of 'used by another process. '?

Tags: c#

I'm trying to delete some file on my code.
But I get an io exception and a message of

"the process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process"

Is there some way to know which process hold a handle to this file?

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/264902/does-anyone-know-of-an-equivalent-of-wholockme-that-works-on-windows-7

Answer (score 0):

Use something like the following application to query which process has a handle on the files you are trying to delete.

[Microsoft Sysinternals Process Explorer](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check this from your code then you can use handle.exe
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896655.aspx
And you will find example on how to use it in Gennadys answer here:
[How do I find out which process is locking a file using .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/317071/how-do-i-find-out-which-process-is-locking-a-file-using-net)