# How do I stop Kibana in Windows?

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I downloaded elasticsearch 5.0.0 along with Kibana.  I started both, but I cannot find any way to STOP Kibana from running - apart from restarting my server (which I do not want to do), `localhost:5601` keeps coming up with Kibana.

I cannot find any documentation online for how to stop this process.

Comment: service manager, run services.msc. in run and from the list find kibana sercvice and stop it

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue several times. It seems that Kibana is running with node.exe.

If you look in your Kibana folder (mine is kibana-5.0.0-windows-x86) you can see a folder called node.

If you try to delete the whole Kibana folder, there are some files locked by node, node.exe itself as well.

I used this c# class **FileUtil** (https://stackoverflow.com/a/20623311/1311130) to find the process and then delete it:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        const string fileLocked = @"E:\kibana-5.0.0-windows-x86\node\node.exe";

        var processes = FileUtil.WhoIsLocking(fileLocked);

        processes.ForEach(p => p.Kill());
    }
}
```

Honestly I think is awful all this hassle to stop a program running, but until a better solution, this is the only one I found out.

Answer (score 3):

In the Task Manager, if you look at the Details tab, you should be able to see `node.exe` in that list and kill the process there.