# Deleting image is blocked by another process

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, image, stream

I have a WPF application which successively displays images from a `ObservableCollection` (includes strings with the image paths)

```
<Image Source="{Binding ListOfUnsortedImages[0], UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
```

This is the collection including the image paths:

```
private ObservableCollection<String> _listOfUnsortedImages = new ObservableCollection<String>();
```

The application displays the image and after clicking a button, the application copies the image, removes it from the collections and shows the next image.

This is the reduced logic of the button:

```
Image img;
var currentImage = ListOfUnsortedImages[0];

using (Stream stream = File.OpenRead(currentImage))
{
    img = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(stream);

    // Do something with the image
    img.Dispose();
    stream.Dispose();
}

ListOfUnsortedImages.RemoveAt(0);
File.Delete(currentImage);
```

The last line fires the IOException:

> The process cannot access the file 'filename' because it is being used
>   by another process

I've tried to solve the issue by using `Dispose()` and/or `using{}` but without success.

Comment: If you skip using block, can you delete file? You will know then if problem is inside this block

Comment: How do you put  your source under your path? May be it will be not released by copy, so you can read, but can not delete? Shure, that no processes use the source, but only your application?

Comment: If you don't want to change your code - you can create converter that will create `BitmapImage` from string with BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad.

Answer (score 0):

Problem might not be in your code since the lock is caused by another process. Have you tried deleting the file using a file manager to see if it's still locked when your application isn't running? Alternatively try ditching the FileStream and use `System.Drawing.Image.FromFile()` instead since you have the filename anyway in your ObservableCollection, see [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/stf701f5(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Yes, I've tried to delete the image by the file manager but the same problem here. I also tried not using FileStream and only use your suggestion, still same problem.

Comment: Maybe there you'll find method to identify which proces is blocking your file:http://stackoverflow.com/q/317071/5358389

Comment: I've also Clear(); the collection before deleting the file, but it also not works. 

@daniell89
If I try to delete the file by a file manager it shows me that the blocking process is vshost32.exe

Comment: Try to run app without debugger (CTRL + F5)

Comment: Now, the app crashes (my test code is not in try catch, so the same problem here)