# IOException was unhandled

Tags: c#, file

I'm working with files on C#, my cose is supposed to delete some lines from a file as mentioned here:

```
 var tmpFile = Path.GetTempFileName(); 
 var LinesToKeep = File.ReadLines(path).Where(l => l.StartsWith("removeme")==false);            
 File.WriteAllLines(tmpFile, LinesToKeep);
 File.Delete(path);
 File.Move(tmpFile,path);
```

but I'm getting an exception: `IOException was unhandled` when running my code saying:

> The process can not access the file because it is being used by another process

in the instruction: `File.Delete(path);`
How can check which process is using file, or there is another reason for my problem?

Comment: [How do I find out which process is locking a file using .NET?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/317071/how-do-i-find-out-which-process-is-locking-a-file-using-net)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use FileShare enumeration to instruct OS to allow other processes (or other parts of your own process) to access same file concurrently.

```
using (var stream = File.Open(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.Read))
{
}
```