# File is being used by another process - Network Share

Tags: vb.net, locking, file-processing

I have a VB.NET application that is attempting to use a file, but the code is throwing an error saying that the file is being used by another process.

I do not need to know if the file is being used by another process because the error already proves that.  I need to know what the other process is that is using the file.

Is there any API I can call to determine what other process is "using" the file in question?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way to check if a file is in use?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/876473/is-there-a-way-to-check-if-a-file-is-in-use)

Comment: This is not a duplicate.  The code has already thrown an error that the file is in use.  I need to determine what process is using the file.

Comment: Might work: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20623311/741136