# Exception: System.UnauthorizedAccessException, Message: Access to the path "" is denied

Tags: c#

I have following function which does text logging but I keep getting below error then and there. Its not coming every time but only sometime and that too at IIS level. IIS Apppool is stopped after this error.

An unhandled exception occurred and the process was terminated.

> Application ID: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT/OrderHelpDesk
>
> Process ID: 81044
>
> Exception: System.UnauthorizedAccessException
>
> Message: Access to the path '\Ser-file\ErrorLog\2018-09\09_27_2018.txt' is denied.
>
> StackTrace:    at OrderHelpDesk.DAL.LogMessage(String Message)
>      at OrderHelpDesk.ViewPendingOrderDetails.AutoGenMailToCSRProcessed(Entity objEntity)
>      at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
>      at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
>      at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
>      at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()

```
public void LogMessage(string Message)
{
     Entity objEntity = new Entity();
     StreamWriter sw = null;

     try            
     {                
         objEntity.LogMessage = string.Format("\r\n{0:MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt} : {1}", DateTime.Now, Message);
         objEntity.LogFilePath = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("ErrorLogPath");
         objEntity.LogFolderName = string.Format("{0:yyyy-MM}", DateTime.Now);
         objEntity.LogFilePath = objEntity.LogFilePath + objEntity.LogFolderName;

         if (!Directory.Exists(objEntity.LogFilePath))
         {
             Directory.CreateDirectory(objEntity.LogFilePath);
         }

         sw = File.AppendText(objEntity.LogFilePath + "\\" + string.Format("{0:MM_dd_yyyy}", DateTime.Now) + ".txt");
         sw.WriteLine(objEntity.LogMessage);
     }
     catch (Exception Ex)
     {
         throw Ex;
     }
     finally
     {
         sw.Close();
     }
}
```

Comment: Did you see `'\Ser-file\ErrorLog\2018-09\09_27_2018.txt'` path is correct? also, iis_user has a permission to read/write to that folder?

Comment: Yes, That path is correct. iis_user has permission for this folder to read and write. The problem is, its not throwing this error every time but occasionally, I don't know under what circumstances can this happen.

Comment: As per your title I think you are getting blank path.

Comment: If you can, better use a logging library such as Serilog. This problem is already solved, you don't have to re-implement it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use already implemented logging libraries like [NLog](https://nlog-project.org/).

if you can't

This happens because LogMessage can be called simultaneously by several threads. In this case one thread will get log file, while the other will get AccessDenied and your pool will crash because sw is null, but you call sw.Close().
Use [synchronization primitives](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/threading/overview-of-synchronization-primitives) and [using](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75483/1099716) construction (or check sw for null sw?.Close()):

```
static object locker = new object();
public void LogMessage(string Message)
{
   lock (locker)
   {
         Entity objEntity = new Entity();                        
         objEntity.LogMessage = string.Format("\r\n{0:MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt} : {1}", DateTime.Now, Message);
         objEntity.LogFilePath = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("ErrorLogPath");
         objEntity.LogFolderName = string.Format("{0:yyyy-MM}", DateTime.Now);
         objEntity.LogFilePath = objEntity.LogFilePath + objEntity.LogFolderName;

         if (!Directory.Exists(objEntity.LogFilePath))
         {
             Directory.CreateDirectory(objEntity.LogFilePath);
         }

         using (StreamWriter sw = File.AppendText(objEntity.LogFilePath + "\\" + string.Format("{0:MM_dd_yyyy}", DateTime.Now) + ".txt"))
         {
             sw.WriteLine(objEntity.LogMessage);
         }  
   }
}
```

Comment: It also can happen, because another process is locking the file. [Determining the locking process is possible](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20623311/107625).

Comment: @UweKeim even though it should not crash IIS pool and I don't think that you need to write complicated logic to determine who is locking. It's better to create another file in that case.

Comment: @Access Denied, Thanks for the answer. For the quick solution I can use above code and for the long term, I can switch for NLog as this will solve all problems related to logging.

Answer (score 0):

It might be the issue of file/Folder Permission.