# C# How can I close an open file with .Net Framework?

Tags: c#, file, process, system.diagnostics

I need my program to be able to close given files by their names.
I played around with processes but came to the realization that I cannot get the process itself properly.

Say I have a "Text.txt" notepad file open I want to close. I tried

```
   var processesToKill = Process.GetProcessesByName(processName);

   foreach (var process in processesToKill)
   {
       process.Kill();
   }
```

but came the conclusion that the friendly file name does not help in any way for that so `processesToKill` is left empty (no such process, duh).

So I get that I have to use, say "notepad" as the `processName` but I need the program to close different file types/open programs (word, excel, chrome, random .txt or .mp3 files, etc.).

My question is, is there a way to get it to do that without writing massive blocks of code checking under what process the opened file is and close it via CloseMainWindow() or the likes?

Sorry for the rather confusing explanation of the issue, hope I didn't give you too much of a headache/

Comment: Please see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/317071/how-do-i-find-out-which-process-is-locking-a-file-using-net) question

Answer (score -1):

if you use , using statement, it will close the file automatically , after reading. below is just a sample example on how it works.

```
String path = @"C:\Text.txt";

    using (StreamReader sr = File.OpenText(path))
    {
     String s = "";

     while ((s = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
     {
      Console.WriteLine(s);
     }
```

Comment: I think OP is asking about files opened in other programs, not in the one OP is writing.

Comment: I need it to close already opened files from other programs, not by the one I'm writing.